# How can I change dynamically post_max_size and upload_max_filesize dynamic?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using cakephp. I have to changed the value of `post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 100M` only in `one page` url will be `www.example.com/imports/uploadImage`.

> I was trying this:

```
        @ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
        @ini_set('post_max_size','100M');
        @ini_set('upload_max_filesize','100M');
        phpinfo();
        exit;
```

After some R&D I get to know they fall in **PHP_INI_PERDIR**. Here is the list which can change by ini_set: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

> PHP_INI_PERDIR    Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or
>   .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

How can I change post_max_size and upload_max_filesize only for one page? I don't won't to set globally.

Is there any way to set only for one page in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or
.user.ini?

Comment: as far as I remember, this is the way to set it in PHP `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` i dont know why in ur syntax u have `@` symbol

Comment: you can write @ini_set('display_errors', '1'); or ini_set('display_errors', '1'); @ prefix will not show any error on page.